# Is the solution to this power series correct?

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

Find all z for which the series

∑(in)$^2$z$^n$
converges.

Using the ratio test I got |z| < 1

And it diverges if |z|=1

Answer (score 1):

What you did is fine. The only thing that needs to be added to it is that, since it diverges when $|z|=1$, it also diverges when $|z|\geqslant1$. Of course, you can also deduce from the ratio test that the series diverges when $|z|>1$.